# How can I visualize the render of a design on a cylinder object in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, 3d

I'm not sure Inkscape can do that but I did a sketch of a sticker and I'd like to visualize it on a cylinder object (bottle).

I know Inkscape is not about 3d (even if you can do some things).

What I would like is have my model on the left and a cylinder on the right, and with some tricks moving the model on the left would move a copy of itself curved on the cylinder (to simulate a rotating cylinder).

It's just a global idea and maybe there is something a lot more easier but I didn't find anything useful for now.

Comment: Can you tell us something about your efforts? Have you given a look to the [Envelope Deformation](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-LivePathEffects-EnvelopeDeformation.html)?

Comment: yes I did look into this, my issue is the fact that my design take more of the half of the bottle, so there is parts who are hidden. but i'd like to be able to see them too, which mean to have tho possibility to rotate or simulate rotation of the cylinder

Comment: Have you tried to split in two the image to be warped: the front size and the rear size; and to deform the two part separately? If you mean to do an animation, it's better use Blender or POV-Ray.

Comment: A simplified sample image for starting point and desired result would be fine.